# How to speed up creating orders programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, orders, programmatically

I have a script that creates orders in Magento 2.

```
<?php
/**
 * ExtendedRma Helper
 */
namespace Company\Module\Helper;

class CreateOrder extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $invoiceService;
    protected $transaction;
    protected $invoiceSender;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender $orderSender,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Rate $shippingRate,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\InvoiceService $invoiceService,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Transaction $transaction,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->orderSender = $orderSender;
        $this->shippingRate = $shippingRate;
        $this->invoiceService = $invoiceService;
        $this->transaction = $transaction;
        $this->invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        $productHelper->setSkipSaleableCheck(true);
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /*
    * create order programmatically
    */
    public function createOrder($orderInfo)
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $storeId = $store->getStoreId();
        $websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $quote = $this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for our quote
        /* for registered customer */
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($orderInfo['customer_id']);
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer

        //add items in quote
        foreach ($orderInfo['items'] as $item) {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($item['product_id']);
            if (!empty($item['super_attribute'])) {
                /* for configurable product */
                $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($item);
                $quote->addProduct($product, $buyRequest);
            } else {
                /* for simple product */
                $product->setPrice($item['custom_price']);
                $quote->addProduct($product, intval($item['qty']));
            }
        }

        //Set Billing and shipping Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderInfo['shipping_address'])->setCustomerAddressId(null);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderInfo['shipping_address'])->setCustomerAddressId(null);

        // set shipping method
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                                    ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
                                    ->collectShippingRates();

        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method, please verify checkmo must be enable from admin
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //decrease item stock equal to qty
        $quote->save(); //quote save
        // Set Sales Order Payment, We have taken check/money order
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);

        // Collect Quote Totals & Save
        $quote->collectTotals();
        $quote->setCreatedAt($orderInfo['date_added'])->save();
        // Create Order From Quote Object
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);

        $order->setCreatedAt($orderInfo['date_added']);

        if($orderInfo['order_status'] == 'Delivered' || $orderInfo['order_status'] == 'Dispatched' || $orderInfo['order_status'] == 'Billed' || $orderInfo['order_status' == 'Transferred']){
            $this->createInvoice($order);
        }

        switch ($orderInfo['order_status']){
            case 'Pending':
                $orderStatus = 'pending';
                $orderState = 'new';
                break;
            case 'Complete':
                $orderStatus = 'pending';
                $orderState = 'new';
                break;
            case 'Processed':
                $orderStatus = 'confirmed';
                $orderState = 'new';
                break;
            case 'Billed':
                $orderStatus = 'billed';
                $orderState = 'processing';
                break;
            case 'Transferred':
                $orderStatus = 'transferred';
                $orderState = 'processing';
                break;
            case 'Dispatched':
                $orderStatus = 'dispatched';
                $orderState = 'processing';
                break;
            case 'Delivered':
                $orderStatus = 'delivered';
                $orderState = 'complete';
                break;
            case 'Product Missing':
                $orderStatus = 'product_missing';
                $orderState = 'holded';
                break;
        }

        $order->setStatus($orderStatus)->setState($orderState);
        $order->addStatusHistoryComment(__('Order Migrated from old system:old orderId #%1.',$orderInfo['old_order_id']))->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
        $order->save();
        /* for send order email to customer email id */
        //$this->orderSender->send($order);
        /* get order real id from order */
        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
        if ($orderId) {
            $result['success'] = $orderId;
        } else {
            $result = ['error' => true, 'msg' => 'Error occurs for Order placed'];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function createInvoice($order){
        if($order->canInvoice()) {
            $invoice = $this->invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order);
            $invoice->register();
            $invoice->save();
            $transactionSave = $this->transaction->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
            $transactionSave->save();
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);
            //send notification code
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Invoice created #%1.', $invoice->getId())
            )
                ->setIsCustomerNotified(false)
                ->save();
        }
    }
}
```

I have another php code that calls the above function `createOrder` in a loop of over **10000**.

Now the issue is, at start it creates order at around **100 orders/minute**, over the time the average reduces to around **30 orders/minute**.

If an order at start has 10 items in it, then it completes at faster rate then an order after couple of minutes, having 1-2 items.

Does PHP slows down over time or Magento indexes something due to which order creation slows down?